# Bokeh datatable reorder columns

Tags: python-3.x, datatable, bokeh

When I read the Bokeh documentation on datatable the reorderable option seems to indicate that drag and drop reordering is possible.

”Allows the reordering of a table’s columns. To reorder a column, click and drag a table’s header to the desired location in the table. The columns on either side will remain in their previous order.”

I can not get this to work. Code below. Does any one know how this works?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x1', 'x2'])
n=10
np.random.seed(0)
df['x1'] = np.random.rand(n)
df['x2'] = np.random.rand(n)

source = ColumnDataSource(df)
columns=[TableColumn(field=Ci, title=Ci) for Ci in df.columns]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, name="table", sizing_mode="scale_both", reorderable=True, sortable=True, fit_columns=True)
l1 = widgetbox([data_table])

curdoc().add_root(l1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure how well it is documented, but if you look on the browser JS console, you will see the reason why:

> [bokeh] – "jquery-ui is required to enable DataTable.reorderable"
>   document.js:1

We don't automatically include jq-ui because there is no way to justify that amount of package bloat just for this one tiny feature. (Which evidently almost no-one ever tries to use, this is the first question about it in ~6 years).

So, you will need to make a template for your Bokeh app, and explicitly load `jquery` and `jquery-ui` yourself in the template. Something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can see an example of using a template for a Bokeh app in the [gapminder example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/gapminder).